# how to make ImageView which is between two elements to margin left of the 'left element' using RelativeLayout?

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout

What I want is to make the 'edit' ImageView between '6.4 MB' TextView and '···'TextView, and let 'edit' ImageView close to '···'TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/screenshot"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/screenShot"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Video Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/videoName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />

    <TextView
        android:text="2021.05.19 · 5:11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#797675"
        android:id="@+id/recordDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoName"
          />

    <TextView
        android:text="6.4 MB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#797675"
        android:id="@+id/videoSize"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/videoSize"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="···"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/moreAction"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

If I use android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" in 'edit' ImageView, then the 'edit' ImageView will disappear. 
Why android:layout_marginLeft is noting working?
anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/screenShot"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/videoName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
    android:text="Video Name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="23dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recordDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/videoName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
    android:text="2021.05.19 · 5:11"
    android:textColor="#797675"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/videoSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
    android:text="6.4 MB"
    android:textColor="#797675"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

**<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moreAction"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_content_cut_24" />**

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/moreAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:text="···"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I shall remove

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit"
```

and add

```
android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
```

the complete  'edit' ImageView code is like below:

```
<ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/edit"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/videoSize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
            />
```